# React fetch to flask route that handles google auth gives CORS error

Tags: reactjs, flask, oauth, google-oauth, flask-login

I have Google auth setup in Flask via OAuth. I have check that it works manually.

My app uses React on the frontend so I have created a login button to hit the login route in flask.
Here is the React fetch request to run that route.

```
  function handleLogin() {
    fetch('/login')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle error
      });
  }
```

Here is my flask routes that have proven to work when I visit the /login route on the flask run location.

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    google = oauth.create_client('google')
    redirect_uri = url_for('authorize', _external=True)
    return google.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)

@app.route('/auth')
def authorize():
    google = oauth.create_client('google')
    token = google.authorize_access_token()
    resp = google.get('userinfo').json()
    # Check if the user already exists in the database
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=resp['email']).first()
    # If the user doesn't exist, create a new user
    if not user:
        user = User(email=resp['email'], google_id=resp['id'])
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
    # Log the user in using Flask-Login
    login_user(user)

    print(f"\n{resp}\n")
    return redirect(url_for('list_all'))
```

The error I receive when I hit the React button that runs `handleLogin` is a CORS error.

```
Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200
Fetch API cannot load <url for google's sign on>
Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200
```

I have tried returning URL that gets redirected in the `/login` route, then having the React code do the redirect on its own. But this results in a `raise MismatchingStateError() authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.MismatchingStateError: mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.`

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
   ...
   authorization_url = google.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)
   redirect_url = authorization_url.location
   return {"status" : 200, "url" : redirect_url}
```

```
fetch('/login')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        // Redirect to authorization page
        console.log(response.url)
        window.location.href = response.url;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle error
      });
```

Comment: @Salad I redesigned. I handled authentication in React via @react-oauth/google, then sent the auth token to Flask instead, where I then handled creation of a jwt token, using jwt python library